# Karate test cases are failing after updating to jdk version 1.8.0_111

Tags: karate

I am unable to run my test cases.Below is my Configurations and IDE used -
Maven: 3.6.0
JDK: 1.8.0_111
IDE: Intellij
karate Version:0.9.0

Caused By `com.intuit.karate - javascript function call failed: ReferenceError: "karate" is not defined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Karate requires at least version 1.8.0_112 or greater. This is mentioned in the docs.

Comment: I am using Java 9 but still getting same error. Please help  error
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.script.ScriptEngine.createBindings()" because "com.intuit.karate.ScriptBindings.NASHORN" is null
 at com.intuit.karate.ScriptBindings.createBindings(ScriptBindings.java:152)

Comment: @AjeetYadawa you are using an old version. create a new fresh project, follow this process and you should be able to figure this out on your own: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue